# HTML/Javascript calender. Range of dates doesn´t work

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I´m trying to do this simple weekday calculator and I can´t get the range of dates to work. For example if I type in 2012-05-31 it says it´s out of range (1-30), but since there´s 31 days in the month of May it´s not correct. Can somebody explain why it´s not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">


<title>Weekday calculator</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: maroon; color:white; font-family: helvetica; text-align: center;}
h1 {font-size: 50px;} 
table { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
    text-align:right; background-color:#993300 ; border: 5px solid
        firebrick }

</style>
</head>


<body>

<h1>Weekday calculator</h1>
<br>

</p>

<br><br>

        <form id="dateForm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Year</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="year" value="" size="8"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Month</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="month" value="" size="8"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Day</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="day" value="" size="8"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="handleInput(this.form);"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <p id="output"></p>

        <script language="Javascript">
        function handleInput(form) {
            try {

                var strYear = form.year.value;
                var strMonth = form.month.value;
                var strDay = form.day.value;


                var intYear = parseInt(strYear);
                var intMonth = parseInt(strMonth);
                var intDay = parseInt(strDay);


                if (isNaN(intYear))
                    throw "Incorrect input. Year is not a number.";
                if (intYear < 0 || intYear > 9999)
                    throw "Incorrect input. Year is out of range (0--9999).";


                if (isNaN(intMonth))
                    throw "Incorrect input. Month is not a number";
                if (intMonth < 1 || intMonth > 12)
                    throw "Incorrect input. Month is out of range (1--12).";


                if (isNaN(intDay))
                    throw "Incorrect input. Day is not a number.";          
                if (intMonth == 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12)
                    if (intDay < 1 || intDay > 31)
                    throw "Incorrect input. Day is out of range (1--31).";

                if (intMonth == 4, 6, 9, 11)
                    if (intDay < 1 || intDay > 30)
                    throw "Incorrect input. Day is out of range (1--30).";

                if (intMonth == 2)
                    if (intYear % 4 == 0 && intYear % 100 != 0)
                        if (intDay < 1 || intDay > 29)
                        throw "Incorrect input. Day is out of range (1--29).";





                var output = "It´s a... "  ;
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
            }
            catch (error) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error;
            }
            }
        </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define `not working` please. And create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what's happening

Comment: @giorgio: No, not a fiddle. Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) so it's complete on-site.

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: I've done some *basic* formatting for you, but when asking for help, using consistent, standard indentation, avoiding long runs of blank lines, etc., all make it easier for people to read your code and therefore help you.

Comment: Yeah, whatever. Anyway, make sure there is a working snippet for us to work with ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
if (intMonth == 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12)
```

JavaScript (and most languages with similar syntax to JavaScript) don't have that syntax to compare a value to a list of values. (It's not a syntax error because JavaScript, somewhat atypically, has the *comma operator* and that `if` ends up being `if (12)`.)

Instead, either use `||`

```
if (intMonth == 1 || intMonth == 3 || ...)
```

Or use a `switch`

```
switch (intMonth) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    // ...
        // Code for these months here
        break;
    case 2:
        // Code for Feb here
        break;
    // ...
}
```

Or use a lookup object:

```
var maxDays = {
    1: 31,
    2: null, // Handle leap years separately
    3: 31,
    4: 30,
    // ...and so on
};
var maxDay;
if (maxDay == 2) {
    maxDay = /* handle leap years*/;
} else {
    maxDay = maxDays[intMonth];
}
```